# Will docker pull update if repo tag updated?

Tags: docker

If use `docker pull xxx`, the docker in fact will pull `xxx:latest`.

Q1: If the latest of remote updated, `docker pull xxx` will also update the local? I mean in the same machine.

Q2: How about other tag? What if do `docker pull xxx:0.1`, and later I update the tag of `0.1` to other docker commit. If it will be renew by `docker pull xxx:0.1` after `0.1` nolonger the old `0.1`?

HELP!HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: yes, `docker pull xx` will be update local image with `latest` version.

A2: yes, if there was renewed. but it won't be renewed normally if it tagged, the developer will release a new version rather than modify old version normally.